# Reload the JFrame or JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im developing an little "clicker" but, if i press the button, and i should get 1+ Score, it dont work! Is there any way to reload or anything else?
Heres my code: (ClickEvent)

```
public class event implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("PRESS");
    game.timesClicked.add(1);
    points.setText(game.seePoints);
}
```

}

And there is my JFrame:

```
public class game extends JFrame
{
public static JButton buttonStart;
JButton buttonCredits;
JButton buttonBack;
JButton buttonLeave;

public static JFrame panel = new game();

public static ArrayList<Integer> timesClicked = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static JLabel label1;
public static JLabel points;
public static String seePoints = "Deine Knöpfe: " + timesClicked.size();
public game()
{

    setLayout(null);
    label1 = new JLabel("ButtonClicker");
    points = new JLabel(seePoints);

    points.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    points.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);

    label1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
    label1.setBounds(315, 50, 500, 200);

    event e1 = new event();

    JButton b = new JButton("KNOPF");
    b.setBackground(new Color(96, 140, 247));
    b.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    b.setFocusPainted(false);
    b.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    b.setBounds( 402, 380, 180, 50 );


    b.addActionListener(e1);

    add(b);
    add(label1);
    add(points);

}
}
```

(Sorry For My Bad English)

Comment: I should note that `public static` variables all over the place is generally poor programming practice.  Look up "encapsulation" for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String seePoints = "Deine Knöpfe: " + timesClicked.size();
```

This is only being called once at the start of your program.  When you add to `timesClicked`, it does not recalculate `seePoints`.

You will need to set this variable to the correct value every time you click.